# How to break line in ChoiceSet of Adaptive Card on Teams?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

When displayed on Teams, I cannot try to break the text in the ChoiceSet.
Line breaks can be made on BotEmulater and Adaptive Card Designer.
But I don't understand why you can't do it on Teams.
If anyone knows why this happens, please let me know.

The Json of Adaptive Card is as follows.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.2",
    "body": [
        {
        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
        "choices": [
            {
                "title": `choice1  \n test`,
                "value": `choice1  \n test`
            }, 
            {
                "title": `choice2  \n test`,
                "value": `choice2  \n test`
            }, 
            {
                "title": `choice3  \n test`,
                "value": `choice3  \n test`
            }, 
            {
                "title": `choice4  \n test`,
                "value": `choice4  \n test`
            } 
        ],
        "id": "choice1",
        "style": "expanded",
        "wrap": true,
        "isMultiSelect": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Hey, can you try to use \n\n  or \r\r ? think that makes a diffference for MS Teams.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting this to us. We could repro it and i have raised a bug for this. Currently we do not have an ETA for the fix to share with you.

Comment: Is this OK with the understanding that there is no solution yet at this time?

Comment: Yes. Currently there is no solution for this. We are working on fixing the bug.

Comment: thank you very much.  
Are you a Microsoft person and fit?  
For this issue, I am waiting for a date to be fixed.

Comment: @GousiaBegum  this is still an issue. It's been > 1 year!

Answer (score 0):

currently, markdown is supported only on Textblock, Fact title, and Fact value on Teams [Text formatting in cards - Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html).